# init let properties with reference to self in subclass in swift

Tags: swift

I'm learning swift and coming across the following problem very often. I will have a class with a property that feels as if it should be a `let` property as it will only be set once. I'd also like this child object to maintain a reference to its owner, which should also be a `let` property, as the parent relationship will not change. The problem arises when the parent class subclasses another class and all `let` properties need to be set before `super.init ()` is run but requires a reference to `self` to init.

Here's a quick example

```
class NodeView: UIView {
    let _nodePlugView: NodePlugView

    init (node: Node) {
        _nodePlugView = NodePlugView (parentView: self)
        super.init ()
    }
}
```

Of course, I could just use `var` for these `_nodePlugView` but it doesn't feel quite right. Is there another pattern that people would recommend?

Comment: This has been asked and explained many, many times on SO. — Also please show only real code when you ask a question. `let _nodePlugView` is not a legal line of Swift code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good use case for an implicitly unwrapped optional.

The Apple [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#) states:

> “Implicitly unwrapped optionals are useful when an optional’s value is
>   confirmed to exist immediately after the optional is first defined and
>   can definitely be assumed to exist at every point thereafter. The
>   primary use of implicitly unwrapped optionals in Swift is during class
>   initialization.”

This means that you can use an implicitly unwrapped optional when a property depends on some aspect of self (but not the superclass) when it is initialised.

The property will be nil until it is set in the `init()` method and then must never be nil again.

```
class NodeView: UIView {

    var _nodePlugView: NodePlugView!

    init (node: Node) {
        super.init()
        _nodePlugView = NodePlugView (parentView: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if `_nodePlugView` is `var`, not `let`, which is what the OP is asking how to avoid.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for my case. As @rmaddy says I was looking for a solution that avoided a `var` but an implicitly unwrapped optional is probably the best trade off. If you change the `let` to `var` so this compiles I'll mark is as the correct answer

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. I wasn’t at my computer so hadn’t tested this by compiling, which is not ideal. I was not aware this would have to be a `var`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `lazy` variable.

```
lazy var _nodePlugView: NodePlugView = NodePlugView(parentView: self)
```

Lazy variables are initialized after the object itself is initialized.

If you really need this to be a let constant, an alternative might be to have an initializer for NodePlugView that doesn't take the parentView parameter, and have a method for setting the parentView after it's been initialized.

```
let _nodePlugView: NodePlugView

init (node: Node) {
    _nodePlugView = NodePlugView()
    super.init()
    _nodePlugView.setParentView(self)
}
```